# How to force horizontal scrolling depending on size of contents

Tags: html, css

I want to have a horizontal scrollbar if necessary, by having the 'child' divs be added side-by-size instead of getting pushed to the next row when the parent isn't wide enough.

My code is below. If you set .mid to have width: 1000px you'll see what I'm going for, only I only want it to be as wide as the dynamically generated children.

```
<html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css">

        .parent {
            width: 400px;
            background-color: #666;
            overflow:scroll;  /* cater to the older browsers */
            overflow-y:hidden; /* Hide vertical*/
        }

        .mid {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .child {
            display:inline-block;
            background-color: #ccc;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 190px;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="mid">
            <div class="child">
                I am a child.
            </div>
            <div class="child">
                I am a child.
            </div>
            <div class="child">
                I am a child.
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're probably going to need Javascript for this. Would you accept such a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People have been here before and found the best / easiest way to do this. Look here:

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/

Answer (score 3):

Heck, might as well answer this. You're going to need Javascript for this, but given that you already use that to dynamically generate the child elements, it shouldn't really be a problem.

Assuming you're using jQuery, add these two lines after you generate the element:

```
var child = $('child');
$('.mid').width(child.length * child.outerWidth(true));
```

---

**Sorry about the miscommunication**

*Using this, however, will create another problem.* When you use `display: inline-block`, a whitespace added behind each `div`, so jQuery cannot get the correct width. This wouldn't happen if you use `float: left` instead though.

Comment: I'm actually generating the children in a loop in Rails, not javascript. It sounds like you're saying float: left would solve the problem too, but that didn't work.

Comment: @99miles: No, I mean that the two *together* will solve your problem. I generally dislike using `display: inline-block` to get elements lined up beside each other.

Comment: no he is saying that add in some dynamic code to figrue out how many elements you have in the side scroller then set the width of mid..

Comment: @Kieran. Kind of tired of saying this but *no*, what I'm saying, in the second part, is that when you use `display: inline-block`, you get an extra space behind each of the boxes, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rEbWu/. So, when using jQuery for the calculation, you need to use `float: left`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use `overflow:auto`

Comment: or have i misunderstood the problem